# Get other columns(attribute) with max values

Tags: sql, database, oracle, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

my dataframe

```
ID      COURSE_ID SEC_ID SEMESTER YEAR  GRADE
00128   CS-101    1      Fall   2009    A
00128   CS-347    1      Fall   2009    A-
12345   CS-101    1      Fall   2009    C
....
```

I want to get course_id & sec_id with the maximum number of registrants(count(id)) at 2009 fall.

so, I tried

```
select course_id, sec_id, enrollment
from (select course_id, sec_id, count(ID) as enrollment
    from takes
    where semester = 'Fall' and year = 2009
    group by course_id, sec_id)
```

However, this will result in each class having registrants. I want to show only those classes with the **maximum** number of registrants. I think I need to use **max**, but now I need to solve it with subsection of this code, from.(from subquery)

++ Can I solve it using the having clause?
I would appreciate it if you could let me know if you can.

thank you for reading.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: What if two have the same value?

Comment: @GordonLinoff In this dataset, it is not duplicated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter on courses from Fall 2009, aggregate by `course_id` and `sec_id`, sort the results by their number of rows per group, and use a row-limiting clause to get the most attented course:

```
select course_id, sec_id, count(*) no_registrants
from takes
where semester = 'Fall' and year = '2009'
group by course_id, sec_id
order by no_registrants desc
fetch first 1 rows with ties
```

This allows top ties, if any. If you want just one row, you can change `fetch first 1 rows with ties` to `fetch first 1 rows only`. You might also want to add a second sort criteria to make the results deterministic (otherwise, it is undefined wich course will appear in there are ties).

---

In Oracle < 12c, where the row limiting clause is not available, you can use `rank()` instead (or `row_number()` to disallow ties):

```
select course_id, sec_id, no_registrants
from (
    select 
        course_id, 
        sec_id, 
        count(*) no_registrants,
        rank() over(order by count(*) desc) rn
    from takes
    where semester = 'Fall' and year = '2009'
    group by course_id, sec_id
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding for your requirement, your query need just modification to get the proper result.

To get only one record with the highest number of registrants. Use your same query just add the below mentioned changes:

```
select course_id, sec_id, max(enrollment) as registrants
from (select course_id, sec_id, count(ID) as enrollment
from takes
where semester = 'Fall' and year = 2009
group by course_id, sec_id) as Rdet group by course_id,sec_id;
```

This will give you the proper result based on you requirement.

Comment: This will work with sql server. Are you using which server? And which version?

Comment: `Are you using which server` - the question is tagged [Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle/info).

Answer (score 0):

You can place your subquery in a CTE to reuse it:

```
with
x as (
  select course_id, sec_id, count(*) as enrollment
  from takes
  where semester = 'Fall' and year = 2009
  group by course_id, sec_id
)
select *
from x
where enrollment = (select max(enrollment) from x)
```

Comment: yes, I did it using 'with',, It was a problem solved using the from clause.